# XCode Cant' Edit CoreData Model

Tags: ios, core-data

After adding a CoreData Model to my existing project using

`File > New > File... > Core Data > Data Model`

I am unable to edit the model. The project now includes a .xcdatamodeld package reference, but clicking on it in Project Navigator has the same effect as clicking on a folder or group, the current editor does not change. Also right clicking the reference and selecting "Open As >" lists no potential editors. Furthermore, opening the file inspector panel only lists settings for "Identity" "Target Membership" and "Text Settings", it does not list settings for "Core Data Model" or "Versioned Core Data Model"

Not that this should have any effect on XCodes ability to recognize a file type, but I have also referenced CoreData.framework in build phases, and included the necessary Core Data properties in the AppDelegate.

What's strange is I have opened the .xcdatamodeld package in Finder to expose the internal .xcdatamodel (note no trailing 'd'). Double clicking that file will open XCode with the Core Data Model Editor as expected.

Even stranger still is, I created a new projected and clicked the "Use Core Data" check box. Doing so allowed me edit the data model by selecting the .xcdatamodeld reference in the Project Navigator. Hence my machine and XCode are capable and configured to edit CoreData files.

It's as if XCode is unable to use Core Data unless the original project was created with the "Use Core Data" check box.

Has anyone experienced this issue, were you able to fix it, and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode 4.5.2 here does not have that problem in the simplest case.  Is there anything odd about the read/write protections for the file/package.

Comment: I also added a model to an empty application (xcode 4.5.2), no problems editing here. You are also not supposed to edit the files with any other editor then xcode.

Comment: I'm running Version 4.5 (4G182). I haven't edited the files outside of XCode. I haven't touched the file since I created it.

Comment: Upgrading to 4.5.2 had no effect. I should mention I'm using Cocoapods. Creating a new project or project in a workspace without core data, then adding a data model does seem to function perfectly. Is there some workspace setting or that could be causing this?

Comment: Amazingly this bug still exists in Xcode 6 two years after this was originally asked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turns out I was attempting to add the Data Model to a group which referenced a specific folder in which to store it's children. That folder however did not exist. This cause XCode to place the data model in the project root, but at the same time reference it as residing 2 directories above the project root. What's even odder is that XCode didn't list the file as missing by displaying it in red. Either way XCode ignored the file when clicked in Project Navigator, because it didn't really exist where it thought it did. Moral of the story is: check your file paths and configured group paths.

Comment: Incidentally, this also means the data file remains if you try to delete the model you added- as it has the wrong path for that file.

Must be an Xcode bug, surely

Comment: Seems like an xcode bug.  In my case I was building a submodule in a subfolder.  I removed the whole folder and re-added (after adding my data model), this caused the paths to be added correctly.

Answer (score 30):

I ran into this issue today, and the problem was that my `.xcdatamodel` file was packaged *inside* itself (strange, I know). Here's how I fixed it:

1. I found my `File.xcdatamodel` file in Finder.
2. Right-clicked and selected **Show Package Contents**.
3. Inside was another copy of `File.xcdatamodel`. I copied that to my Desktop.
4. I then dragged that file into Xcode and it opened.

What a relief. :) I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Same here.  The way I "managed" to do this was to copy an .xcdatamodeld from another project, delete all of the versions except one, and then add the wrapping .xcdatamodeld to the project.  I think that maybe when you add an unversioned model, you should add the inner .xcdatamodel, not the .xcdatamodeld.

Answer (score 5):

Our real problem was that Xcode couldn't open/validate the data model when creating a new version.
Meaning: having first one .xcdatamodel and then `Editor > Add Model Version... > MyProject 2` (as .xcdatamodel).
After what, the MyPoject.xcdatamodel**d** was created but couldn't be opened.

After hours investigating we figured out that the .xcurrentversion file and the `XCVersionGroup` in the project file were missing or invalid.
One of the reason was that the xcdatamodel**d** version should be in the root folder.

### Easy Fast Solution 1:

Create a new Model Version and:

1. Set the path to the root folder
2. Specify the `Group` to be the subdirectory where the previous version is.

The new .xcdatamodel**d** will now **work on Xcode but can't be moved anywhere else than the root folder**.

### Complicated Solution 2:

To have a wroking .xcdatamodel**d** in a subfolder, hou have to modify manually the project file follwoing those steps:

PS: This is the most complicated and hacky answer I evcer wrote. I'm sorry :(

1. Create a new Model Version (even though it invalidates the data model) in the same directory of the previous version.
2. Make sure the new .xcdatamodel**d** file is specified in your target(s).
3. Open the Package Content in Finder and drag-and-drop all xcdatamodel versions to the project.
4. Open the `project.pbxproj` file in a text editor.
5. Search for the new files for all data models and copy their `fileId`.

Example:

```
75F3199D1B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject 2.xcdatamodel in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F319981B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject 2.xcdatamodel */; };
// fileId = 75F3199D1B9D80D50030FF46 /* The first id at the beginning of the line */
```

6. Move those lines from the `PBXBuildFile` section to the beginning of the `PBXFileReference` one and update them like this (reuse the `fileId`).

Example:

```
75F3199D1B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject 2.xcdatamodel */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.xcdatamodel; path = "MyProject 2.xcdatamodel"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

7. Now search the file `MyPoject.xcdatamodeld` in the `PBXBuildFile` section and copy its `fileRef`.

Example:

```
75F319961B9D7FA50030FF46 /* MyProject.xcdatamodeld in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 75F319931B9D7FA50030FF46 /* MyProject.xcdatamodeld */; };
// fileRef = 75F319931B9D7FA50030FF46
```

8. Finally, at the very end of the `project.pbxproj` file create the `XCVersionGroup` section and reuse the `fileRef` from the xcdatamodel**d** and all `fileId`.

Example (without the `//` comments):

```
/* Begin XCVersionGroup section */
        75F319931B9D7FA50030FF46 /* MyProject.xcdatamodeld */ = { // fileRed
            isa = XCVersionGroup;
            children = (
                75F3199D1B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject 2.xcdatamodel */, // fileId
                75F319A11B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject.xcdatamodel */, // fileId
            );
            currentVersion = 75F3199D1B9D80D50030FF46 /* MyProject 2.xcdatamodel */; // fileId of the current version
            name = MyProject.xcdatamodeld;
            path = Path/To/MyProject.xcdatamodeld; // set the correct path
            sourceTree = "<group>";
            versionGroupType = wrapper.xcdatamodel;
        };
/* End XCVersionGroup section */
    };
    rootObject = 7564EB681B4AB1560065394B /* Project object */;
} /* EOF */
```

8. You should now be able to open the xcdatamodel**d** file in Xcode now from the desired subfolder.
9. Now remove the extra references of the single xcdatamodel files from xcode (the ones created in the beginning).

Sorry for the long answer... but problem solved :D

Comment: I did it slightly differently, but that seems indeed like the only way to fix it without having to move the model to the root of the project every time one needs to edit (see answer from @TamarackBob). Removing and adding back the file did not solve the issue. It really looks like a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This is still a problem in Xcode 8.

For me, the simple solution was to drag (inside the project file navigator pane - left hand side of Xcode) my .xcdatamodeld file from its (yellow) sub group folder up to the very top level under the App (the one with the blue icon).
After that, it opened up with the editor immediately.

I retested by dragging it back to the sub-group, and again it would not open in the editor, then back to top level and it opened correctly...
I have no idea why this is happening, but at least I can edit it again.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Xcode usually takes care of this problem.

Comment: Restarted XCode and my machine. Even ran lsregister -kill to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the issue:

1. In Xcode file tree, deleted the .xcdatamodeld file.
2. When I opened the project folder, the file was there. (Xcode only removed the reference.)
3. I've dragged it back to Xcode file tree, checked "Copy items if needed". It didn't make a copy because understood that the file is already under the project folder.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

On first selection this behavior happens but selecting another class then back to the dataModel allows editing for me on a fresh project without CoreData then adding the coreData model to the project.

Just a thought, did you add an entity or are you not even able to access the datamodel view?

Comment: I can't even access the datamodel. This method does not work for me. XCode essentially treats the package as an unknown file type.

Comment: Does this behavior happen on a fresh project without CoreData then adding a model?

Comment: MarkM, no it does not. A fresh project with a data model added after the fact does, indeed, work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this in Xcode:

**Right click on your project** (not your project folder, I mean that one **with the blue Xcode Icon**!), than select "New File" and choose the right folder to save the data model.

Note: Clicking "New File" on the project folder itself or on one of its subfolders did not work somehow..