# .xcdatamodeld file not showing data model structure in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-data, watchkit

I have .xcdatamodeld file in my project but it not opening up into the data model.

When I click on the file in the left sidebar in Xcode, it continues to display the contents of the previously selected file instead of displaying the data model. Likewise, when I right click on the file and choose "Open As >", I cannot select to display it as a Data Model—nothing comes up. I checked out the code from the SVN repo and even the filer owner is not able to see it in his workspace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a symptom that I have seen from time to time. In at least one case, this was due Xcode having the wrong path stored in the `path` component of the `XCVersionGroup` section of the project.pbxproj file, and having an apparently unnecessary additional `name` component in that section. It would probably be possible to manually edit this file, but I'm always reluctant to monkey around with the project file directly, and fortunately there's an easier way.

1. Navigate to your .xcdatamodeld file in the Finder. The easiest way to do this is Right click/Ctrl-click on the .xcdatamodeld file and select "Show in Finder".
2. Drag the file from the Finder and drop it immediately above or below the current reference to the .xcdatamodeld in the Project Navigator in your Xcode project.
3. Click OK to accept the import, ensuring that you are adding it to the correct targets. (Which targets are correct will depend on your project.)
4. You will now have two references to the same file in your Project Navigator. Clicking on *either* of them will now bring up the desired data model structure.
5. Remove the duplicate reference to the model file. Click on one of the file references (doesn't appear to matter which, though it may be better to remove the old one) and press Delete.
6. In the resulting confirmation dialog, be sure to select "Remove Reference" only, and do NOT move the file to the trash. (The two references point to only one actual file in the file system. Moving to trash would thus trash the only copy.)

You're now left with just one reference to the data model, and it works.

One thing that appears to trigger this bug is moving the .xcdatamodeld file in the file structure on disk. Even after correctly re-associating the file with the new location (i.e., it no longer appears in red in the sidebar), the one section of the Project file mentioned above is not correctly updated, and thus the file is not treated fully correctly as an Xcode Data Model file.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue in Xcode 6.3

The only solution that worked for me was to **move the .xcdatamodeld file out of my 'Resources' folder and into the project root folder** in the Xcode project explorer (location on the filesystem doesn't matter)

I'm still not sure why, just moving the location of the file in the project structure causes it to not show up at all when clicked.. but apparently, at least in my setup, it doesn't like living in the Resources folder..

Comment: That is actually the problem... and its solution. But, I found a way to still have the xcdatamodel**d** where ever you desire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728021/xcode-cant-edit-coredata-model/32435681#32435681

Answer (score 4):

For some dark reasons, sometimes Xcode needs the xcdatamodel**d** fiel to be in the root folder.
I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728021/xcode-cant-edit-coredata-model/32435681#32435681) that explain how to do this, but also a workaround to have this file where ever you would like to.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The `.xcdatamodeld` file is a package. It contains `.xcdatamodel` packages, one for each version of the model. Inside every `.xcdatamodel` there is a `contents` file, which is an *XML* with entities description. To see what is inside your packages, right-click them in Finder and choose *Show Package Contents* option.

[image: Show Package Contents in Finder]

Perhaps you didn't add the `contents` file into your repository. This way you will not be able to see your model when you create a brand new working copy from it.

Comment: There is another file in that package, whose name I can't remember at the moment (perhaps layout) that can become corrupted. Delete that file and reopen and Xcode should create a new layout with visible elements.

Answer (score 2):

I was victim of this problem today on Xcode8.

I solved it simply by placing the xcdatamodeld file outside any group in the Project navigator (left pane). As soon as I move it into a group, I can't open the little guy anymore.

Comment: Worked for me too. What's frustrating is that the issue happens also for newly created files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Xcode 7.3.1.

It turned out to be related to the way the data model packages were configured.

I discovered that there was one embedded model package nested inside another. Let's say a top level data model called FolderNodes.xcdatamodeld containing  another with exactly the same name ... FolderNodes.xcdatamodeld. Inside FolderNodes.xcdatamodeld is the actual contents file that has the model info.

The solution for me was to drag the embedded package FolderNodes.xcdatamodeld ( number 2) into the Xcode project and NOT its enclosing folder.

Apple uses the package for versioning but I think the logic associated with moving the data model file somehow breaks the original package creating a redundant wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `Version Editor` is not active.

Having the `Version Editor` open results in the xml code to be displayed instead of the `Data Model`. You will also not be able to choose `Data Model` in the context menu of the xcdatamodeld file within the `Project Navigator`.

Answer (score 0):

Happens on XCode 8.3 as well.

For me, moving the physical file to a different folder, then deleting the original reference, then adding it back to same place and establishing the reference again does the job.