# Cannot add model version xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration, xcdatamodel

I've added new model version before in this project but for some reason I cannot add them now. When I right click on `****.xcdatamodeld` and select **"Add model version"** from **Editor** menu. New version is showing up in Finder when I click **"Show in Finder"** but not under `****.xcdatamodeld` nor in `File Inspector`??? I cannot add them manually under `****.xcdatamodeld` as well.

I've added Apple Watch support in my project recently, in case if this information helps.

Comment: To start, restart Xcode / Mac & delete Derived Data, maybe caches too.

Comment: @sschale its not working

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think I found a satisfactory answer but a few workarounds to what I think is a bug.

A solution here refers to incorrect directory structure, I did not give this a try as the xCode versions seem quite old but maybe it might help you: [Issues with directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646800/xcode-data-model-editor-not-appearing)

[This seems like a hack which worked for some, even in xCode 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026349/xcode-data-model-problems-with-appearance-in-editor)

While none of these options worked for me, even quitting xCode, restarting Mac, I just had the beta 7.1 lying around, adding a new version worked perfectly  and then I switched back to 7.3 to continue the rest.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think I found a satisfactory answer but a it solved my problem.i created a new project, in that project I did my model versioning(in latest xcode) and copied that model object in to my project.It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Having just experienced watching nothing happen after selecting `Add Model Version`, I quickly found (stumbled upon) a solution that works. Credit goes to Shawn's hack link, in which Mundi points to the xcdatamodels.

1. Alt-select an xcdatamodel and then Show in Finder
2. Quit Xcode
3. In the Finder folder with all the versions, I found one version already existed (but wasn't showing in Xcode) with the version I had tried to make several times.
4. Delete this imposter!
5. Open Xcode and try Add Model Version
6. The new version was added.